# CART for regression: Avoid impossible combinations

Tags: r, cart, rpart

I want to predict a categorical variable using also categorical predictors. Currently, I am looking at classification and regression trees (CART).

The prediction quality is "good enough", except for the presence of impossible combinations. In the following minimal example, the combination `a==2, b==2` is impossible, yet the estimation decides not to use `b` for splitting.

```
> library(rpart)
> d <- data.frame(a=rep(factor(c(1,1,2)), 100000), b=factor(c(1,2,1)))
> xtabs(~., d)
   b
a       1     2
  1 1e+05 1e+05
  2 1e+05 0e+00
> (tr <- rpart(a~b, d))
n= 300000 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 300000 1e+05 1 (0.6666667 0.3333333) *
```

When simulating stochastically from this model (by choosing the leaf value by sampling using the annotated probability vector, here $(2/3, 1/3)$, as weights), the combination `2, 2` will occur:

```
> prob.m <- predict(tr, d, type="prob")
> d$a.sim <- apply(prob.m, 1, function(x) sample.int(length(x), size=1, prob=x))
> xtabs(~a.sim+b, d)
     b
a.sim      1      2
    1 133041  66615
    2  66959  33385
```

Is there a way to avoid this, perhaps using another method?

This is just a small example for a more general case. I have around 10 predictors, and I want to exclude all combinations of two (or perhaps three) attributes that have no observation in the sample.

I am aware of the "loss matrix" that can be specified as a parameter to `rpart`, but this is prohibitive if many predictors are used.

Comment: What do you mean, "the combination 2, 2 will occur". Your model is just the root, so whether you try to get a predicted class from a = 1 or 2, you'll get b = 1.

Comment: @HongOoi: Not if I predict stochastically, i.e. use the vector $(2/3, 1/3)$ (in the root node) as probabilites to sample from. Will update my questions.

Comment: What if you make 'b' a factor as well?

Comment: @PeterFlom: My mistake, but this doesn't change the output.

Comment: The toy example is a little silly.... and "predicting statistically" from this toy example is more silly. In your actual data, do any nodes include only impossible combinations?

Comment: And what is your intended sample size?  rpart requires tens of thousands of observations to yield stable trees (more if there are continuous predictors).

Comment: @PeterFlom: I have edited the example, now there are 300000 observations to learn from. Is this any less silly? -- For the actual data, there are no "impossible only" leaf nodes, only such where impossible and possible combinations are mixed.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I use a 5% sample of the Swiss census as input, that's more than 300k observations. I have edited the code.

Comment: Since in the actual data there are no impossible nodes, I think you are inventing a problem that can't happen in real life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force `rpart` to split down to a single observation per node:

```
rpart(a~b, d, control=rpart.control(minsplit=1, minbucket=1, cp=-1))
```

(The value `cp=-1` means to stop splitting if the improvement in cp is less than or equal to -1. This is just a way of taking this criterion out of the picture.)

Comment: How will this affect the generalization error (see my edit, second-to-last paragraph)? I want a model after all, not a replication of the dataset...

Comment: Are you not risking generalisation error by arbitrarily excluding "impossible" response levels, without prior knowledge of what counts as impossible?

Comment: Not in this particular case. I have more than $10^5$ observations, and if a particular combination of two or three attributes (with up to six classes in each attribute) doesn't occur, I consider it impossible.

Comment: However, `cp=-1` **does** help indeed. Thank you!

Comment: @krlmlr I would *strongly* advise *against* doing this! With these options (as HongOoi implies) you'll be hopelessly overfitting the response. This might help the toy example fit a more complex tree, but you still need to prune it back using the cost-complexity value under crossvalidation.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Thanks for your input. Actually, it seems like I need a different splitting function, 0/1 loss just doesn't seem to be good enough. Any way to achieve this using `rpart` (or, for that matter, R)?

Comment: @krlmlr Why don't you just give the loss matrix and place a large, but equal cost on the combinations that you consider impossible? With 10 predictors that is only 100 combinations to state and most of these do not need to be modified.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: I'll try that. But why is it only 100 combinations with 10 predictors? Isn't it something like $2^10$ for 10 binary predictors, more if the predictors have more classes?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating the post to have a large sample size.

I think the 'solution' is now clear: There isn't a problem!

In one of your comments you note that with your actual data, no nodes include only impossible values. So, no problem there.

In the example with huge N, again the tree creates only a root node: That is, it performs as it should.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have added simulation results right from the start. See my edit. I don't expect the combination (2,2) to be generated at all. The situation in the original data is very similar.